# Sorting on date not working when date format is DD/MM/YYYY in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

When we have a column with type date with date format is DD/MM/YYYY in Handsontable and we sort on this column the result is not correct.

Please find the fiddle below.
http://jsfiddle.net/3nwhsm7v/

```
   var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: financeData,
  colHeaders: ["Price", "Date", "1D Chg", "YTD Chg", "Vol BTC"],
  rowHeaders: true,
  stretchH: 'all',
  sortIndicator: true,
  columnSorting: true,
  contextMenu: true,
  manualColumnMove : true,
  columns: [
    {type: 'numeric', format: '$0,0.00'},
    {type: 'date', dateFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY', correctFormat: true},
    {type: 'numeric', format: '0.00%'},
    {type: 'numeric', format: '0.00%'},
    {type: 'numeric', format: '0.00'}
  ]
});
```

Thanks